# IOS Web App open links within web app

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I am in the mist of creating a mobile web app and have both meta tags

I have an iphone 5 on 7.0.4

When I click on a regular link like the one below it, opens up a mobile safari window and leaves the webapp.  I also tried setting the target to _self and same behavior.

Sign in

I then used my ipad which was on 7.0.3 and it worked as should, not opening mobile safari on links. I think proceeded to update my ipad to 7.0.4 and the same issue as I had on my ipad.

Anyone ran into this issue and or knows a fix ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and narrowed it down to the exact thing you did. Searching frantically for the answer. I am running a site (that I own so all links are relative). 7.0.4 is the only difference. Before, they didn't kick you out of the "app".

Comment: @BradSherman I submitted a bug report with apple and waiting on a reply

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 7.0.4 all links in WebApps open in Safari. As a workaround you can use Javascript:

window.location.href='text.html'

But remember that these steps will not be captured in history (so there is no ability to use Javascript like history.back() ..).

Alternatively, if you are using a menu in your web app, try to combine iframe and Javascript, you can change the content of your iframe with this Javascipt:

document.getElementById("frame").src = new_content.html

This will prevent your WebApp to open up links in Safari and stay in WebApp view.